# Assets pipeline exclude list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm using rails to compile some static html files.

They are in the assets/html folder and subfolders, so I added this to my application.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/html"
config.assets.precompile += %w( */*.html )
```

Is there a way to define an exclude list?

Example: all files that starts with "_" (like _test.html.erb) should not be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

config.assets.paths is supposedly a regular ruby array. This means that before compilation you can apply an action like reject to it. Try this:

`config.assets.paths.reject! { |path| path =~ /^_/i }`